# How wrire secure web application

Tags: security, web-applications

I need of an information. I'm new in develop web application.  I should use php and javascritp but it 's possible, in the future, I could use other languase like Java. During these days I'm following a course on the best practice to write secure code.
Is there any guide/book or any other valid resource, where I can find an explanation about the differrent kind of attaks on a web application and the ways to solve them?

Thanks
Luca

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for resources to secure your applications on the internet, the first thing to try is OWASP, or Open Web Application Security Project. Here are some useful articles about what you're looking for:

- [OWASP: Web Security Testing Guide](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/stable/)
- [OWASP: Cheatsheets](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/)
- [OWASP: General Information](https://owasp.org/)

All of the resources above will show you the recommended ways to secure your web application against threats. I think it's more than enough for the first step in the security world.